# Is there a more efficient method of planting trees?

Tags: cities-skylines

Planting trees in Cities: Skylines is a bit of a nightmare. I keep planting all these trees but they're only planted one at a time.

[image]

Is there an easier method of planting trees that doesn't involve mindlessly spam clicking an area until there's no more room for trees?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to currently plant trees in the game is one-by-one.

There is a [Tree Brush](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=406723376) which will allow you to place multiple trees at a time, but it looks like the mod hasn't been updated since the latest patch (which broke a lot of mods), so it's not currently working. Since it's a mod, it will disable achievements. There is a [mod to prevent mods from disabling achievements](http://steamcommunity.com//sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=407055819), but it appears to have broken with the latest patch as well.

Comment: A mod that mods other mods? So that would be a... metamod? :p

Comment: @Thomas: It's mods all the way down.

Comment: @Thomas: Actually, it just mods the game itself, flipping the "AreModsEnabled" (just a guess) boolean. Not sure on the name, but the mod creator said he's literally just flipping a boolean the right way up again.

Answer (score 1):

### With mods:

**Method 1:** Place a few trees in an area and use [Move It](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=766190099) to copy and paste them to fill a larger area. This is more tedious than method 2 but allows much more control.

**Method 2:** Use the brush tool with [Extra Landscaping Tools](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=502750307). This is better at filling very large areas than smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Assets creating tool to make parks that contain only trees. This way you can quickly fill up big spaces next to roads.